# MediaPlayer plays only one time

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer

I get a path of music file from my listview using startActivityForResult and then set that string for MediaPlayer with `MediaPlayer.setDataSource(STRING);` First time I play the song with button it plays all right, and if I click button while song is playing it will reset and play again.

```
  if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                  mMediaPlayer.reset();
         }
```

But if I tap on button playback is completed it will not play again.

startActivityForResult

```
Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Activityone.class);
                    startActivityForResult(i, 0);
                    mMediaPlayer.reset();
```

In Listview :

```
 music_column_index = musiccursor
.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA);
String filename = musiccursor.getString(music_column_index);
Intent person = new Intent();
Bundle backpack = new Bundle();
backpack.putString("arnswer", filename);
person.putExtras(backpack);
setResult(RESULT_OK, person);
finish();
```

onActivityResult :

```
  if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
               if(requestCode == 0) {
                // handling code of startActivityForResult of first button
               Bundle basket = data.getExtras();
                 s = basket.getString("arnswer");
    }
```

and Button to start MediaPlayer :

```
public void pbutton1(View view) {
       try {
           if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                 mMediaPlayer.reset();
        }
         mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(s); //using string here
         mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        mMediaPlayer.start();
   } catch (Exception e) {

   }
```

LogCat :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to `mMediaPlayer.seekTo(0)` in order to replay, because it has finished.

[See the android doc page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).

---

Edit:

Looking the diagram [image] between `Started` <-> `PlaybackCompleted` seems to be only one action in order to restart the player... you do not need `prepare` which you have :( ...

I understand the reason why *you want `prepare`* so I suggest `OnCompletetionListener` to `mMediaPlayer.stop()` so as to move to `Stopped` state and be ready for next `prepare()`!

Comment: That will only play sound twice.

Comment: much better! added an other suggestion!

Comment: I just added OnCompletionListener and added mMediaPlayer.stop(), still same results, after song finishes it cant be played again till I dont load it again

Answer (score 0):

This code works perfectly. I hope to help you.

```
public class PianoActivity extends Activity {

private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_piano);
    setupUI();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void setupUI() {
    findViewById(R.id.doo).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            managerOfSound();
        }
    });
}

private void managerOfSound() {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.doo);
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } else {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.reset();
            mp.release();
        }
    });
}
```

}